# Postgres.App + Django and proper path to libgeos_c.dylib on OSX?

Tags: django, postgres.app

I have succesfully installed Postgres.App. It works just fine if I have this in settings.py:

```
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/lib/libgeos_c.dylib"
```

If I remove the above line and execute `manage.py loaddata mydata`, I get:

```
ImportError: Could not find the GEOS library (tried "geos_c", "GEOS"). Try setting GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.
```

The question: **is it possible to make things work without GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH set in settings.py?** The reason is that in our team not all are using OSX + Postgres.App and the path is not the same for all developers. Django Docs mention usage of LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but having the next line exported in bash did nothing:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/lib/"
```

I still get the same error. Am I having a wrong syntax or is there another solution so that everyone can have individual path to the library?

Comment: What about a local  settings.py for each developer? You will probably have more system dependent entries (like cache directory)

Comment: That is not the case now but things might change. So yes, that is one option. It still would be great if only this path problem could be separated from the rest of settings.py which are common for everyone and in central repo. And I wonder why LD_LIBRARY_PATH doesn't work or what am I doing wrong with it.

Comment: You can create a `local_settings.py` with the GEO_PATH and a `base_settings.py` with the common settings. The do `from base_settings import *` in `local_settings.py`.

Comment: That sounds very good solution if the LD_LIB.. doesn't work. Thanks, will try it!